# Not able to figure out how to solve this as \$I(s)\$ is used in the feedback

Tags: pwm, power-electronics, boost, feedback, buck-boost

I am not able to figure out the approach to this problem because \$I(s)\$ is connected to feedback instead of \$V(s)\$
[image]

[image]

Comment: I think you need to explain what you are asking in more detail before you will get a reply that can genuinely help you.

Comment: Also show what you have tried, yourself, just so others won't think you're trying to make them solve your problem for you (which you aren't, are you?).

Comment: This looks like a power factor correction circuit in which the input current scaled in voltage by a resistance (or a current transformer) is compared to an instantaneous voltage reference \$v_{ref}(t)\$. Nothing insurmountable here. Start by determining the operating mode (DCM or CCM) to infer the static (or quiescent) values then use an average model to draw the small-signal model. The stimulus is the duty ratio while the response is the input current. This drawing is coming from CoPEC, right?